# invalid resource directory folder in android when generating folder for strings

Tags: android, xml, localization

I created the folder **/values-el_rGr** under res in order to place the **strings.xml** for the greek language and I get the error:

```
invalid resource directory folder
```

I read prevous answers but you do not suggest anything, only that resources names bust me only these:[resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/available-resources.html). But I have read in these 2 tutorials [Link1](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/available-resources.html) and [Link2](http://www.wilsonmar.com/android_localization.htm) that I can generate that folder and use it for localisation. So what I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have created the folder **/values-el_rGr** under res. Here you are using "underscore"

just it by replacing with **/values-el-rGr**

Refer this [localization-tutorial](http://www.icanlocalize.com/site/tutorials/android-application-localization-tutorial/)